# Ember render without or empty layout

Tags: templates, ember.js, render

Good day

I'm trying to render a view template without layout or into empty layout without success.

Here is my code in the route:

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model){
    this.render('myViewTemplate', {// the template to render, referenced by name
        into: 'otherLayout', // the template to render into, referenced by name
        outlet: 'main' // the outlet inside `options.template` to render into.
    })
}
```

I get an error message: other_layout cannot be found.

other_layout.hbs is into templates folder and it has:

```
{{outlet}}
```

any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use underscore you must use camelCase,

Change your code to

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model){
    this.render('myViewTemplate', {// the template to render, referenced by name
        into: 'otherLayout', // the template to render into, referenced by name
        outlet: 'main' // the outlet inside `options.template` to render into. {{outlet}} and {{outlet 'main'}} are synonymous,
    })
}
```

you may need to add controller assigned to this route, for instance :

```
  controller: 'post',  // the controller associated with the 'post' Route
```

hopefully, it works.

[check this out](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate)

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    let favController = this.controllerFor('favoritePost');

    // Render the `favoritePost` template into
    // the outlet `posts`, and display the `favoritePost`
    // controller.
    this.render('favoritePost', {
      outlet: 'posts',
      controller: favController
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes I used camelCase, sorry I set controller and model,also and get the same error message

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Im using Ember 2.4.0

Comment: apparently this is an issue in 2.4 https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10780 --> Having this issue on 2.4.0

Comment: yes but in current version I dont know it was solved, if I'll upgrade the application maybe I need to do some changes..

Comment: I suggest test here https://ember-twiddle.com/ first with Ember 2.9 and then if you got it fixed then update your Ember version. but anyway I am a big fun of staying updated with latest version always so I recommend  once you have tested everything , go ahead and upgrade.